# How do I see all the tasks historically that had a phabricator Herald rule applied to them?

Tags: phabricator

I made a herald rule that had an unintended effect on some tasks in my project. I need to be able to look up the historical log of all the tasks that had the rule applied to them to fix the tasks that were erroneously affected by the rule. Is there anywhere in herald or phabricator that let's me do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is not conduit endpoint for Herald, so you have to check in https://*your phabricator*/herald/transcript/ where all the Herald action trace lies